# Golang runtime error when getting file absolute path

Tags: go

I am almost done with an issue that has stomped me as I am new to Golang, I am basically trying to get the absolute path of a file inside the **os.open** method. I have been trying all types of things but nothing works

```
  func UploadProfile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    infile, header, err := r.FormFile("upload_file")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error parsing uploaded file: "+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    defer infile.Close()


       absolue_path := string(filepath.Abs(header.Filename))
                  // I want to get the absolute path in os.Open
    file, err :=  os.Open(absolute_path)
    }
```

for instance if I hard code the string in the os.Open like
**/Users/Documents/pictures/cats.jpg** then the file uploads successfully . When i try to get the absolute path and put it inside the os.Open I get this error on runtime **multiple-value filepath.Abs() in single-value context** . Is there any other way that I can get the path of the file so that I can put it inside that method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs), `Abs` function will return TWO values, one string and one error.

So you can not have something like:

```
absolute_path := string(filepath.Abs(header.Filename))
```

instead, you should write:

```
absolute_path, err := filepath.Abs(header.Filename)
```

Also note that absolute_path is a string already.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error from this line of code (multiple-value filepath.Abs() in single-value context)

```
 absolue_path := string(filepath.Abs(header.Filename))
```

is telling you that `filepath.Abs` is returning multiple arguments and `string` only takes one argument.

`filepath.Abs` returns a `string` and `error`

Code should be:

```
ap, err := filepath.Abs(header.Filename)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```